# SQL Creating an Alias Column For a Nested Select?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Say I have a `Person` table and a `Courses` table. In the `Person` table I have the column `PersonName`. In the `Courses` table, let's say I have `CourseTitle`,`PersonName` and `CourseDifficulty`. `CourseDifficulty` is 1-4 (4 being the hardest). How do I return a list of people from `Person` and for each person have a column that shows the most difficult class they're taking by `CourseTitle`.

As far as I know, I'd get the CourseTitle of the most difficult class Brett is taking by doing the following:

```
SELECT CourseTitle 
FROM Courses 
WHERE PersonName = 'Brett' 
  AND CourseDifficulty = (SELECT MAX(CourseDifficulty) 
                          FROM Courses 
                          WHERE PersonName='Brett')
```

But how do I run that for each person in the Person table? I want the results to be something like

```
Brett-SQL For Dummies 4
Tim-Quantum Mechanics
Jane-Thermodynamics 2
```

Sorry for the noobness. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you want to happen if a student has more than 1 "Most Difficult Course".  (Oh, and is this homework?)

Comment: No it's for work. I have a much more complicated scenario but this is what I need to do at the most basic level. In this scenario, no one person will have any two courses with the same difficulty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the following

```
SELECT p.name ,p.address, c.courseTitle ,c.courseDifficulty FROM (
        SELECT personName, courseTitle, MAX(courseDifficulty) AS courseDifficulty
        FROM course
        GROUP BY personName 
) AS c RIGHT JOIN person AS p ON p.name = c.personName
```

here am assuming personName is a unique. Otherwise you can use unique id over here instead on person name and add this field in select statement.

Comment: Ah, you CAN use a select AS X then Join X to another table. I think this is going to do it for me. I'll try it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.CourseTitle, c.PersonName, c.CourseDifficulty
  FROM Courses c
 WHERE c.CourseDifficulty=(SELECT MAX(c2.CourseDifficulty) FROM Courses c2 WHERE c2.PersonName=c.PersonName)
```

Comment: What if Brett's most difficult class is a 3, and Bob's most difficult class is a 4. If you only return the 4's Brett will be excluded. I may be reading it incorrectly

Comment: I went ahead and tried it. Out of 1186 records in the Courses table, I got 964 back and it returned all different CourseDifficulty's 1 through 4 and the PersonName column wasn't distinct for each Person.

Comment: This SQL should only return records for those courses that are the most difficult for the person on the record. However, if a person has more than one course at the same maximum difficulty level, it will return all of them. I think that is why you're getting multiples back for the same person ... in this scenario what should be returned?

Comment: No two courses for any one person have the same difficulty rating in this instance.